# How to bind Json data to Html in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am receiving below data from my json object,

```
var dataFromServer='[
    {
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"Province A",
         "AreaDTO":[],
         "SubStationDTO":[]
    },
    {
         "Id":2,
         "Name":"Province B",
          "AreaDTO":[
              {
                  "Id":1,
                  "Name":"ProvinceB Area A",
                  "ProvinceId":2,
                  "SubStationDTO":null
              },
              {
                  "Id":2,
                  "Name":"Province B Area B",
                  "ProvinceId":2,
                  "SubStationDTO":null
              }],
          "SubStationDTO":[
              {
                  "Id":1,
                  "Name":" Province B Area A SubStation A",
                  "AreaId":1,
                  "MetersDTO":null
              }     
          ]
    }
]';
```

Please see : http://jsfiddle.net/Jayaruvan/s8403t71/1/

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Province Name</th>
        <th class="numeric">Area Count</th>
        <th class="numeric">SubStation Count</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ProvincesArray">
    <tr>
        <td><p data-bind="text: Name"></p></td>
        <td ><p data-bind="text: Areas().length" ></p></td>
        <td> <p data-bind="text: SubStations().length" ></p></td>
        <td class=""><a class="btn-link" data-bind="click: $parent.EditProvince">Edit</a></td>
        <td class=""><a class="btn-link" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveProvince">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want it to bind above table and it's not working. Can anyone help?

I am referring this : http://jsfiddle.net/rVPBz/2/ as an example,
(Thank you ace for the proper formatting)

Comment: can you provide the error details ?

Comment: basically, one PROVINCE  can have many AREAS. one AREA can have many SUBSTATIONS. I am reading these details from database and getting via ajax to html. in my debugging i am receiving  above  data once i call my http method and parse like  this "JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(resultOfCallingUrlGetAll));" Now i want to display these data to HTML .

Comment: There are lots of basic syntax errors and typos in the code you posted. I'd suggest you spend some time going though the samples at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make a new Jsfiddle for your. I have fix some basic errors.

The table is implemented.

Your view model implementation was bad, I reorganised it.

```
var ProvinceViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.Province = function(data){ 
        data = data || {};

        this.Id = data.Id;
        this.Name=data.Name;
        this.Areas = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.SubStations = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    this.ProvincesArray = ko.observableArray([new     this.Province()]);

    this.Area = function(data){
    data = data || {};

        this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.SubStations = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    this.SubStation = function(data){
       data = data || {};

        this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.Meters = ko.observableArray([]);
    };    

    this.ProvincesArray = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataFromServer,            function(item) {

        var Province = new self.Province(item);
        var Area= new self.Area(item);
        var SubStations= new self.SubStation();

        return Province;
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ProvinceViewModel());
```

You can see the new structure which work, you can add any paramet

http://jsfiddle.net/YvanBarbaria/s8403t71/15/

Comment: No worries, hope it's unlock you :)